# Access nth item from list of lists when list has no particular pattern

Tags: python

I have this list of lists that has a weird output.

```
['-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90']]
```

I need to access the ipv4 items only (2nd position), but at the same time I also need the `'-'` items.

So the output should be:

```
['-',172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','-','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','-','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','172.29.1.90','-','172.29.1.90']
```

This would work if it weren't for the pesky '-' item.

```
filtered_host_ip_list = [ip[1] for ip in host_ip_list]
```

Any ideas? Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: It might look a lot less weird if you didn't write it in one awfully long horizontal line.

Comment: And your desired output is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add an "if" to your comprehension

The "if" handles the "-", and the comprehension is otherwise the same as your existing one.

```
host_ip_list = ['-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90']]

filtered_host_ip_list = [ip[1] if ip != "-" else "-" for ip in host_ip_list ]

print(filtered_host_ip_list)
```

Result:

```
['-', '172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90',
'172.29.1.90', '-', '172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90', 
'172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90', '-', '172.29.1.90', 
'172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90', '172.29.1.90', '-', '172.29.1.90']
```

Comment: The thing is that I need the '-'. All of them in the same order they appear in the original.

Comment: I think this should do that, yes?

Comment: Have you tested your code? The syntax is incorrect (order of elements)

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on wether the item is a list or not

```
filtered_host_ip_list = [item[1] if isinstance(item,list) else item for item in host_ip_list]
```

Comment: The OP wants to keep the '-' entries...

Comment: Hey, I don't see the '-' in the output. I need all of them, in the same order they appear in the original list.

Comment: @OverflowStack sorry, check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

If the lists can contain more than one IPv4 address, you might want to generalize this to capture them all.

```py
from re import match

ips = ['-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90'], '-', ['fe80::a108:b52e:cfba:a646', '172.29.1.90']]

filtered_ips = [
  ip
  for ip in ips
  for ip in ([ip] if ip == '-' else \
             [i for i in ip if re.match(r"\d{1,3}\.\d({1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", i)])
]
```

Answer (score 1):

> This would work if it weren't for the pesky '-' item.
>
> ```
> filtered_host_ip_list = [ip[1] for ip in host_ip_list]
> ```

Then add ***another*** `-` :-)

```
filtered_host_ip_list = [ip[-1] for ip in host_ip_list]
```

Index `-1` gives you what you want in both cases.